# Does alloc and init is create 2 instance of class?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, init, alloc

I recently learn objective-c from Programming Objective C, 4th edition.
I have question when reading to part:

```
myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
myFraction = [myFraction init];
```

> When you send the alloc message to a class, you get back a new instance of that class. The alloc method is guaranteed to zero out all of an object’s instance variables. However, that doesn’t mean that the object has been properly initialized for use. You need to initialize an object after you allocate it.
>
> Again, you are using a method here that you didn’t write yourself. The
>   init method initializes the instance of a class. Note that you are
>   sending the init message to myFraction. That is, you want to
>   initialize a specific Fraction object here, so you don’t send it to
>   the class—you send it to an instance of the class. Make sure you
>   understand this point before continuing.

So alloc and init is create each instance of class when I send message to class or instance of class?
I'm so confused about this. I searched on google but the result was found nothing. I need your help to make me clearly about it?

All of thing I know is alloc that allocate space in memory so it's actually not be created a new  instance, just give me the address?

Comment: the `alloc` is allocated the memory of the instance and loads into it, the `init` is inits the existing instance, e.g. doing the essential procedure to make the class ready for proper usage. imagine that procedure as buying ingredients for cooking (=alloc), prepare the ingredients and put them into the bowl (=init).

Comment: @holex: thank for you anwser, I have comment the same for Kets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with you just have some available memory with nothing in it.

When you call `alloc`, some of that free memory is reserved for your use for the instance that you are creating. Some basic setup work is done to configure the type of class that the instance is. Then you get a pointer back to the reserved memory location.

Technically, you could use this instance, but, it might not work properly in all cases as it hasn't been initialised. Some classes don't really need initialisation (like `NSObject`), some do. Generally you should never use the instance returned from `alloc` until you have called some `init` method.

After you call `init`, the instance is ready to use.

Sometimes the parameters that you pass to `init` mean that the initial instance that was reserved and created isn't the correct (class) type to use. In this case, it will be destroyed and a new one will be created for you. This is very common in class clusters where you create an `NSArray` instance, but then after calling `init` you might get back an `NSCFArray`. This is why you always need to use the instance returned from the `init` call, even though you already had the instance returned from `alloc`.

Usually you don't need to worry about this, but you do need to follow the rules.

Answer (score 0):

So you always need to `alloc` and `init` an class.

Allocating means you give the class "Fraction" in this case a memory place. Afterwards you need to initialize the class "Fraction" so you can use it.

```
Fraction *class1 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
Fraction *class2 = [[Fraction alloc] init];

[class1 doSomethingWithClass1];
[class2 doSomethingWithClass2];
```

Later on you will learn about singletons. With that you can alloc/init a class one time, and always use that without alloc/init'ing it again.

Comment: thank for your answer, I want to know the behind of them. If you said that, it's absolute clearly to understand but how to?